# If $u \in K$ is transcendental over $F$, then $F(u) \cong F(x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

This isn't for homework, but I would just like a small **hint** please.  The question asks

> Let $K$ be an extension field of $F$.  If $u \in K$ is transcendental over $F$, then $F(u) \cong F(x)$ (where $F(x)$ is the field of quotients of $F[x]$).

I should mention that the definition of $F(u)$ that I am working with is: $F(u)$ is the intersection of all subfields of $K$ containing $F$ and $u$.  I have seen some definitions of $F(u)$ that have $F(u) = \left\{ f(u)/g(u) : f(x), g(x) \in F[x] \right\}$.  This problem is essentially asking me to show that these two definitions are equivalent.

So I defined a function $\varphi : F(x) \to F(u)$ by $\varphi(f(x)/g(x)) = f(u)g(u)^{-1}$.  I have shown that this function is a homomorphism of rings (routine), as well as the fact that it is injective (since $\ker \varphi = \{ 0 \}$), but I am having problems on showing surjectivity.  I would really appreciate a small **hint** to put me back on track.

Comment: You just need to show that the image contains $u$ and $F$. Since the image is a sub-field, it will automatically be equal to all of $F(u)$

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan I see.  That helped me finish it. Feel free to post this as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid checking injectivity/surjectivity by noting that $\varphi$ is invertible, with inverse function $$\varphi^{-1}:F(u) \to F(x) \ : \ f(u) g(u)^{-1} \mapsto f(x)g(x)^{-1}.$$

This is well defined since there every element of $F(u)$ has a unique representation as $f(u)g(u)^{-1}$ (written in lowest terms). This is because two distinct such representations contradicts that assumption that $u$ is transcendental.