# If $K[X]\cong K[a]$ then $K(X)\cong K(a)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $L/K$ be a field extension. I came across the statement "if $a\in L$ is transcendent over $K$, then $K[X]\cong K[a]$, and **thereby** $K(X)\cong K(a)$".

Why is that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe [it](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/563911/if-u-in-k-is-transcendental-over-f-then-fu-cong-fx?rq=1) helps

Comment: You should show that any injective ring morphism $\phi : R \to S$ extends to a field morphism $\tilde{\phi} : Frac(R) \to Frac(S)$ simply given by $\tilde{\phi}(a/b) = \phi(a)/\phi(b)$.

Comment: And you should probably look at the ring morphism $\phi : \mathbb{Q}[X] \to \mathbb{Q}[i], \phi(X) = i$ (is it injective ? surjective ? does it extend to the fraction fields ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If two integral domains are isomorphic, so are their quotient fields.

Comment: That's it, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

**Hints**:

$$\phi:K[X]\to K[a]\;,\;\;\phi p(X):=p(a)\;\;\text{is a ring isomorphism}$$

and thus we can extend it to::

$$\Phi: K(X)\to K(a)\;,\;\;\Phi\left(\frac{p(X)}{q(X)}\right):=\frac{p(a)}{q(a)}$$

Comment: Is there some straightforward top-level reasoning that a such extension is also bijective and an homomorphism? Or do I have to check elementwise, again? This procedure I'd get, but I thought the implication in my question used some "bigger" reasoning.

Comment: @Ramen :  Show that $\phi$ is injective by the definition of transcendent, and It is obviously surjective.

Comment: This argumentation does not need the first isomorphism, does it not? If I have the first isomorphism, does this allow a weaker argumentation to get the second isomorphism?

Comment: @Ramen Why don't you try ? It is really easy, using the definition $K[a] = \{ \sum_{n=0}^N c_n a^n, c_n \in K\}$ and $K(a) = Frac(K[a]) = \{ \frac{p}{q}, p \in K, q \in K^*\}$

Comment: Try what, exactly? I can show injectivity for the above map. I guess I am confused as, reading a proof, I came across: "...It is $K[X]\cong K[a]$, and because of [the representation of your comment] and the **universal property of the field of fractions** [$\Phi$] is an isomorphism, too." Why does the field of fractions of a ring being the smallest field containing that ring help in this argumentation?

Comment: @Ramen Indeed you can pass directly to the second isomorphism. I think though that going through the first one makes things smoother. Also, as you mention, using the corresponding fields of fractions may be useful. As you wish.